# Java array of array [matrix] of an integer partition with fixed term

Tags: java, algorithm, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

for my study purpose I need to build an array of array filled with the partitions of an integer with fixed term. That is given an integer, suppose 10 and given the fixed number of terms, suppose 5 I need to populate an array like this

```
10 0 0 0 0
9 0 0 0 1
8 0 0 0 2
7 0 0 0 3
............
9 0 0 1 0
8 0 0 1 1
.............
7 0 1 1 0
6 0 1 1 1
............
...........
0 6 1 1 1
.............
0 0 0 0 10
```

am pretty new to Java and am getting confused with all the for loops. Right now my code can do the partition of the integer but unfortunately it is not with fixed term

public class Partition {

private static int[] riga;

private static void printPartition(int[] p, int n) {

```
        for (int i= 0; i < n; i++)
            System.out.print(p[i]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void partition(int[] p, int n, int m, int i) {

        if (n == 0)
            printPartition(p, i);
        else
            for (int k= m; k > 0; k--) {
                p[i]= k;
                partition(p, n-k, n-k, i+1);
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     riga = new int[6];
     for(int i = 0; i<riga.length; i++){
      riga[i] = 0;
     }

        partition(riga, 6, 1, 0);
    }
}
```

the output I get it from is like this:

```
1 5
1 4 1
1 3 2
1 3 1 1
1 2 3
1 2 2 1
1 2 1 2
1 2 1 1 1
```

what i'm actually trying to understand how to proceed is to have it with a fixed terms which would be the columns of my array. So, am stuck with trying to get a way to make it 
less dynamic. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    static void partition(int sum, int[] arr, int k) {
        if (k == arr.length - 1) {
            arr[k] = sum;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            return;
        }
        for (int i = sum; i >= 0; i--) {
            arr[k] = i;
            partition(sum - i, arr, k + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        partition(10, new int[5], 0);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[10, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[9, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[9, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[9, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[9, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[8, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[8, 1, 1, 0, 0]
:
:
[0, 0, 0, 5, 5]
[0, 0, 0, 4, 6]
[0, 0, 0, 3, 7]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 8]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 9]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
```

([see full output](http://www.ideone.com/OcZGG))

Comment: Yeah, that's what I really wanted.
Thank you polygenelubricants

Comment: @santacrose: If you need to store these into an `int[][]`, then I suggest you use a `List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();`, and instead of printing out, `list.add(arr.clone());`. Then `int[][] all = list.toArray(new int[0][]);` at the end of the search.

Comment: yes, indeed. I was planning to do it really like that. 
thanks again

Comment: @santacrose: Please consider accepting the answer if it's satisfactory (i.e. click on the green check mark next to answer).

Comment: @polygenelubricants dang, almost five years and it still has not been accepted. good answer.